# The bullet i am firing in my game project in unity seems to be firing backwards towards the player

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am currently on episode 19 of Tom Francis' guide to making a unity game from scratch, i am working on unity 2018.4.32f1 and i am trying to fire my weapon, however, the weapon fires backwards into the player, i am showing the weapon behaviour and bullet behaviour below

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class WeaponBehaviour : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject bulletPrefab;
    public float secondsBetweenShots;
    float secondSinceLastShot;
    public float accuracy; // if accuracy is 0, the game will crash
    public float numberOfProjectiles;
    public AudioSource audioSource;
    public float kickAmount;


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        secondSinceLastShot = secondsBetweenShots;
        audioSource = GetComponent<AudioSource>();

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        //firing
        secondSinceLastShot += Time.deltaTime;
            
    }

    public void Fire(Vector3 targetPosition)
        { 
            if (secondSinceLastShot > secondsBetweenShots)
            {
                //ready to fire
                Debug.Log("T" + targetPosition);
                //this next line makes it so that when you fire your weapon, the enemies immediately start spawning
                references.levelManager.alarmSounded = true;
                audioSource.Play();
                references.screenshake.joltVector = transform.forward * -kickAmount;

                for (
                 int iterationCount=0;  //declare a variable to keep track of how many iterations we've done
                 iterationCount < numberOfProjectiles;  //set a limit for how high this variable can go
                 iterationCount++   //run this after each time we iterate - increase the iteration count
                )
                {
                    GameObject newBullet = Instantiate(bulletPrefab, transform.position + transform.forward, transform.rotation);
                    //offset that target position by a random amount according to our inaccuracy
                    float inaccuracy = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, targetPosition) / accuracy;
                    Vector3 inaccuratePosition = targetPosition; 
                    inaccuratePosition.x += Random.Range(-inaccuracy, inaccuracy);
                    inaccuratePosition.z += Random.Range(-inaccuracy, inaccuracy);
                    newBullet.transform.LookAt(inaccuratePosition);
                    Debug.Log(inaccuratePosition);
                    secondSinceLastShot = 0;
                    //newBullet.name = iterationCount.ToString();
                }
            }
        }

}
```

and for bulletbehaviour

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class BulletBehaviour : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float bulletSpeed;
    public float secondsUntilDestroyed;
    public float damage;


    
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
       Rigidbody ourRigidBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
       ourRigidBody.velocity = transform.forward * bulletSpeed;
        //rigidbody.velocity = transform.forward * bulletSpeed;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    protected virtual void Update()
    {
        secondsUntilDestroyed -= Time.deltaTime;

        if (secondsUntilDestroyed < 1)

        {
            transform.localScale *= secondsUntilDestroyed;
        }

        if (secondsUntilDestroyed < 0)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision thisCollision)
    {
        GameObject theirGameObject = thisCollision.gameObject;
        //after thisCollision. the options are GetEnumerator, GetHashCode, GetType, impactForceSum, impulse, other, relativeVelocity
        //rigidBody, ToString, contacts, Equals, frictionForce\sum, gameObject, GetContact, GetContacts.
        
        
        //them.TakeDamage(1;)
        HealthSystem theirHealthSystem = theirGameObject.GetComponent<HealthSystem>();


        if (theirHealthSystem != null) 
        {
            theirHealthSystem.TakeDamage(damage);       
        }

        Destroy(gameObject);
        
    }


}
```

i saw someone with a similar issue in the comments saying something similar and saying it was due to the fact that the tutorial had us turn the weapons into prefabs and unity messed up the rotation, however all attempts at changing the rotation were for nothing

i checked the orientation of the weapons and bullets respectively, seeing as i saw that was a common error and tried changing it to face forward, however, both were already facing forward:
[weapon orientation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42D8g.png)
[bullet orientation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAbbr.png)
i have asked a friend, who is much better than me at using unity engine and they have said they are also stumped, so i am unsure what to do.
as an example, the guy in the comments said that when he made the guns into prefabs, unity pointed them all in the opposite direction, which has already been tested by me, and i have found that is not my issue, as i basically tried rotating it in all directions and so far, nothing has worked
also, I am unaware of how much this will fit into the problem, but a small amount of the weapon firing is in player behaviour, I will show it below
'if( weapons.Count > 0 && Input.GetButton("Fire1"))
{

```
         //tell our weapon to fire
         weapons[selectedWeaponIndex].Fire(cursorPosition);
        }'
```

Comment: Reset the bullet transform. Rotate it to face the `Z` axis so that the tip of the bullet faces is in the same direction as the blue(Z) arrow.  Your gun barrel should be pointing in the same direction as the blue(Z) arrow. Make sure that the `Transform.Position` of the bullet is set to 0 on on the X,Y,Z axes when instantiating.

Comment: how do i change the transform.position on the bullet? @darko6977

Comment: You can just reset it trough the inspector inside the Unity editor or just manually set the values of X Y and Z to 0. You need to do this to avoid offsets when instantiating the bullet

Comment: @darko6977 I tried doing all of your steps, resetting the bullet to 0 and chcking all orientations, making sure the barrels of the gun face the z arrow, and the bullets face it too, also resetting the bullet coordinate value in the prefab, sorry to say, none of it worked so far

Comment: Have you checked the `targetPosition` value ? It seems that it is the cause of the problem. Can you show us where you are calling your `Fire()` method ?

Comment: @ArcaderMaster Can you show the script where the bullet is shot and the force is applied? Also, give a link to the tutorial you are following.

Comment: @Obscure021 i am not certain what you mean by force, i thinnk i may just be using the rigidbody functions within unity
as for the tutorial, here is the link:
https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLUtKzyIe0aB3TZfe2wsIgJgGZW5G_NAxa

Comment: @darko6977 how would i go about checking the targetPosition value? sorry, im quite new at coding, as for the Fire() method, i believe i am calling that in the weaponbehaviour script in the orginal question

Comment: You can use `print( $"X: {targetPosition.X}, Y: {targetPosition.Y}, Z:{targetPosition.Z}" );` and see if the resulting vector has the value you expect. Also check the way you acquire the `targetPosition` vector.

Comment: @darko6977 when i put in that command, it spit out these errors
Assets\WeaponBehaviour.cs(42,90): error CS1061: 'Vector3' does not contain a definition for 'Z' and no accessible extension method 'Z' accepting a first argument of type 'Vector3' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   (and the same issue for x and y)
as for the target position, i believe it is also defined in the vector 3 section in the code above, as i cant find it anywhere else in my code in 
public void Fire(Vector3 targetPosition)

Comment: Use lowercase x,y,z

Comment: ok, thanks, it works, but the issue still remains, the co ordinates it outputs is around where i put the cursor, which is right, but the bullet still is not firing

Comment: Is it possible your bullet spawn right inside the players collider => the `OnCollisionEnter` immediately triggers? Also not sure but you instantiate and then rotate the bullet .. maybe `Start` was already executed by then? Instead of passing in `transform.rotation` yo could pass in `Quaternion.LookRotation(inaccuratePosition - (transform.position + transform.forward))` directly into `Instantiate`

Comment: @derHugo i input your line of code into mine, then this error came up in unity
Assets\WeaponBehaviour.cs(51,56): error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'UnityEngine.Quaternion' to 'UnityEngine.Object'

Comment: @ArcaderMaster are you sure you have put it as the correct parameter (the rotation one)?

Comment: my bad, i have now input it corre tly (ill show it below just in case i didnt) but the bullets still arent firing out
GameObject newBullet = Instantiate(bulletPrefab, transform.position + transform.forward, Quaternion.LookRotation(inaccuratePosition - (transform.position + transform.forward)));

Comment: @ArcaderMaster no you have not ^^ `GameObject newBullet = Instantiate(bulletPrefab, transform.position + transform.forward, Quaternion.LookRotation(inaccuratePosition - (transform.position + transform.forward)));
                 `

Comment: @derHugo ok i fixed it, but it still is not firing

Comment: what happens instead? Does it not appear at all? Is it stuck in the air? Does it just fall down? etc

Comment: @derHugo the same thing happened as before, the gun is still there, it is still picked up, but does not fire any bullets outwards

Comment: again my question is what exactly happens instead with the bullet? Is no bullet appearing at all? -> This might mean that the bullet immediately spawns within the gun's collider which triggers `OnCollisionEnter` and destroys the bullet again. Or is the bullet just not moving at all? This might mean your bullet's rigidbody is *kinematic*. Or dos the bullet just fall down, move really slow? This might indicate it immediately collides with something erasing the applied velocity

Comment: @derHugo the bullet sometimes does appear, and i believe you are right when you say that it spawns within the gun's collider and triggers it, additionally, the bullet moves backwards and moves into the player, damaging the player, and as for the settings on both the shotgun and the bullet, the bullet has a rigidbody, but is oly affected by gravity, and is kinematic, and the bullet only fires inwards for the shotgun, for the submachine gun, which has a faster fire rate, the bullet fires out briefly, but does not go very far before disappearing and disappears early

Comment: @derHugo ok i have been messing around with more of the prefab and script stuff and i have figured out that the error must be in either the weapon script or the positioning (even though i have tested the weapons and bullets in every rotation i cant rule it out as a possibility) as i took out the bullet behaviour script and it  changed nothing about how the bullet spawned. thank you for the help up to this point btw

Answer (score 0):

if the bullets are moving wrong direction, use transform.localposition insted.
or just transform.backword

Comment: When i do try to use localposition, unity does not recognise it, it says that  "'Transform' does not contain a definition for 'localposition' and no accessible extension method 'localposition' accepting a first argument of type 'Transform' could be found"

Comment: not a Big letter 'T' small letter 'transform'

Comment: i did use a small t in transform, it jus popped up with that error anyway,
this is the exact code i put in
 GameObject newBullet = Instantiate(bulletPrefab, transform.localposition + transform.forward, transform.rotation);
is this about right?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

When the code is executed, transform.position and transform.forward are accessing the position and forward direction of the game object that the script is attached to. The instantiated bullet will be positioned relative to this object's position and will inherit its rotation.

so In your case I think you placed on Weapon parent gameobject and the parent direction is towards the Player. so In instantiation, if you place - sign instead of +, so that will reverese its direction.

if it does not work for you, so comment I will help you in that.

Comment: I think he should fix the root cause instead of just patching the problem up like this. This might work, but the root problem will eventually bite him in the ass.

Comment: if you mean turn the + symbol into a negative symbol for the transform.position + transform.forward, i have already tried it, it just sent the bullet back towards the player from a further distance